# Copy OS to tmpfs from initramfs

Tags: initramfs

I am putting together a new server with 64GB of RAM and I would like to copy the whole Linux OS into a tmpfs from the disk and use the tmpfs as the OS (and I will use rsync to back up the tmpfs to disk every five minutes or so).

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using a traditional ramdisk, as shmfs/tmpfs are not very efficient filesystem-wise.

Also voted to close, as you're not asking a question.