# How can I run Linux from RAM only

Tags: initramfs, rootfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy OS to tmpfs from initramfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/362123/copy-os-to-tmpfs-from-initramfs)

I am putting together a new server with 64GB of RAM and I would like to copy the whole Linux OS into RAM from the disk and run the operating system solely from RAM.

How can I do this?

Comment: you mean, like a ram disk ? -- I wouldn't bother to be honest, linux will cache into ram all the files it uses most often and is really very good at cache management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Live CDs have an option to 'Run from RAM'.

You can find an incomplete list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM

> Technically, other distributions can be made to boot from RAM as well (also referred to as "RAMboot", "toram" or "copy2ram").